# AWS Lamba constantly receiving empty SQS event messages

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I'm a relative n00b at AWS, so apologise if this is a stupid question.

I have an AWS Lambda written in Java. I also have an SQS queue that receives AWS S3 event messages. I've then created a Lambda trigger against the SQS queue so that my Lambda receives the S3 events as SQS messages and processes them appropriately.

It all works well. The only issue I have is that it seems like the Lambda is receiving notification of an SQS event message every 2 minutes, even when there are no messages in the SQS queue.

The Java code looks like this:

```
public class SQSEventHandler implements RequestHandler<SQSEvent, Void> {
    @Override
    public Void handleRequest(SQSEvent sqsEvent, Context context) {
        if (sqsEvent != null) {
            LOGGER.debug("Received SQS event: {}", sqsEvent.toString());
            ... do stuff...
```

If I look in the CloudWatch logs (I log using SLF4J), I can see that the Lambda is triggered with different SQS messages every 2 minutes, even during periods when there are no S3 event messages to process:

```
02:54:16 START RequestId: d5454080-8ea3-4c44-93e9-caa5bd903599 Version: $LATEST
02:54:16 [2020-02-13 02:54:16.220] - [d5454080-8ea3-4c44-93e9-caa5bd903599] DEBUG <package>.SQSEventHandler - Received SQS event: {}
02:54:16 END RequestId: d5454080-8ea3-4c44-93e9-caa5bd903599
02:54:16 REPORT RequestId: d5454080-8ea3-4c44-93e9-caa5bd903599 Duration: 1.05 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 161 MB
02:56:16 START RequestId: 9d5acbba-b96c-47e9-81c2-2d448e4ca6e9 Version: $LATEST
02:56:16 [2020-02-13 02:56:16.386] - [9d5acbba-b96c-47e9-81c2-2d448e4ca6e9] DEBUG <package>.SQSEventHandler - Received SQS event: {}
02:56:16 END RequestId: 9d5acbba-b96c-47e9-81c2-2d448e4ca6e9
02:56:16 REPORT RequestId: 9d5acbba-b96c-47e9-81c2-2d448e4ca6e9 Duration: 1.23 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 161 MB
02:58:16 START RequestId: 54bc4fa4-bcaf-4834-9185-09c9c7e2d757 Version: $LATEST
02:58:16 [2020-02-13 02:58:16.451] - [54bc4fa4-bcaf-4834-9185-09c9c7e2d757] DEBUG <package>.SQSEventHandler - Received SQS event: {}
02:58:16 END RequestId: 54bc4fa4-bcaf-4834-9185-09c9c7e2d757
02:58:16 REPORT RequestId: 54bc4fa4-bcaf-4834-9185-09c9c7e2d757 Duration: 1.01 ms Billed Duration: 100 ms Memory Size: 512 MB Max Memory Used: 161 MB
```

There are no other SQS queues with triggers to this Lambda.

As you can see, the SQS event object isn't null but doesn't produce anything in the toString() call.

I can't work out what the issue is - any assistance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unbeknownst to me, there was a CloudWatch rule set up to send a message to my Lambda every two minutes. Once this had been located, I disabled the rule and the Lambda was no longer triggered.

Comment: Could you share how you find out about it? I'm hoping to target the same issue on my end! Thanks :)

Comment: @CyrilN.: I just looked through my CloudWatch (now EventBridge) rules. There weren't many deployed in my AWS environment at the time.